# Vertical scroll appears sharepoint

Tags: 2013, css, ie, style

i have an issue where a few of the users (not all) are experiencing in SharePoint in IE (works fine in chrome). Whereby when you try to scroll using the scroll bar another appears.
Any ideas?

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask